# Is there a way to suppress Kotlin's default import?

Tags: kotlin

Is there a way to suppress (e.g., via a commnad line flag passed to the compiler) Kotlin's default import of multiple packages? or - alternatively - to be selective about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy, just use your alternative to replace it by using `as`, and the default import will be replaced by your one.

Here's a simple example, if you want to use `java.lang.String` instead of `kotlin.String`, although it's not recommended, this is just an example.

```
import java.lang.String as String

// here, String is not `kotlin.String`. 
private fun main(vararg args: String) {

}
```

BTW there's a trick about refactoring, like if you want to replace all `Any` used in a file with `java.lang.Object`, put this after the package declaration:

```
import java.lang.Object as Any
```

And the implicit import to `Any` is suppressed and superseded by `Object`.